# python: post key/value pairs in request body

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have an existing python API using flask that submits a post request in the body, then calls and executes another python script:

testingREST.py:

```
import testingdf 
import json 
from flask import Flask, json, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/results", methods=['POST'])
def createResults():
  entry = request.get_json().get('entry', '')
  passcode = request.get_json().get('passcode', '')
  data = testingdf.test(entry, passcode)
  response = app.response_class(
      response=json.dumps(data),
      status=200,
      mimetype='application/json'
  )
  return response     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, host='localhost', port=8080, passthrough_errors=False)
```

testingdf.py:

```
import pandas as pd



def test(entry, passcode):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    testInput = zip(entry, passcode)
    for entry, passcode in testInput:
        df = df.append({'Entry': entry, 'Passcode': passcode}, ignore_index=True)
        results = {
            'Entry' : entry,
            'Outcome' : passcode,
                }
    return results
```

This is what I post into the request body when calling the api

```
{
"entry":[21, 44, 31],
"passcode":["denied", "Try Again", "Retry"]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "Entry": 35,
    "Outcome": "Success"
}
```

Problem: In the request body, instead of having one variable for 'entry' and another for 'passcode', is there a way that I have something like this as the request body:

```
{
"entryInfo":[(21, "denied"), (44, "Try Again"), (31, "Retry")]
}
```

Basically, passing them in as pairs since I think the way I've implemented it is weird where it can easily be mismatched. Also, I'm not sure if "key/value" is the correct term to use here but I hope this helps.

Using python3 by the way.

Comment: Each iteration of your loop, you *reset* the dictionary with `results = { ... }`, so only the last such dictionary is returned. I'm not sure that that is very efficient or even intentional.

Comment: In fact, you don't really use the `df` dataframe at all to inform the function result. You could just use `return {'Entry': entry[-1], 'Outcome': passcode[-1]}` as the `test()` function body, and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to boil down to what data to pass to the flask server. There is also another issue about what you do with that data (you're only returning the last one), but you did not ask about that.

Send this as the request body. It uses list notation which is valid JSON. Your flask server can then access the list by decoding the JSON request.

```
{"entryInfo": [[21, "denied"], [44, "Try Again"], [31, "Retry"]]}
```

A better way though might be to use a dictionary mapping entry codes to pass codes:

```
{"entryInfo": {"21": "denied", "44": "Try Again", "31": "Retry"}}
```

and it's debatable whether the top-level dict is required, you could get away with:

```
{"21": "denied", "44": "Try Again", "31": "Retry"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! using the list notation worked! 2 questions, what do you mean by "flask server can then access the list by decoding the JSON request."?   also, why do you think using dict mapping is the better way to implement this?

Comment: 1. `request.get_json()` decodes the received JSON string giving a Python object, in this case a dictionary. 2. Since you seem to want to associate each entry with a passcode it appears that you want to _map_ one to the other, hence using a dictionary. I don't know if that makes sense to your application because your test function doesn't seem to do anything sensible with the data.